# Assign value returned by AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity{
.
.
.
// I have this method to run If the login button is pressed.
public void login(View v){

// I am performing all verification and validation
// Just not showing it here
// To store the keys
String api_key_from_database;
String api_key_from_network;

//Gets the key from the database
api_key_from_database=db.getApiKey(database,email);
api_key_from_network=httpRequest.getHttpResponse(email,password);;// I am having problems with this assignment

//Compare the two keys to authenticate
if(api_key_from_database.equals(api_key_from_network)){
       //Start the main activity
       //This is just placeholder to start the actual activity.
       startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));
       //End this login activity
       finish();
   }
else{
// Throw error
}
}
}
```

Since `getHttpResponse()` performs a network activity, I cannot run it on the `Main Thread`.

In the line where I assign `api_key_from_network` the value returned by the `getHttpResponse` method, I cannot seem to assign using both `Thread` and `AsyncTask`

In using `Thread`, Since the variable `api_key_from_network` is not declared as `final`, I am unable to access the variable.

```
new Thread(){
  public void run(){
  }
}.start();
```

If I declare it as `final`, I cannot modify the value.

Now using `AsyncTask`, I am not exactly sure how to return the value. 
In `doPostExecution()`, I cannot seem to assign the value either.

Can you please help me to assign the value returned by the method to  `api_key_from_network`

Comment: you can use one interface to carry your return value

Comment: @Sree can you elaborate

Comment: if you want to use AsyncTask you can assign data to any variable in post Execution.

Comment: @Shvet How do I do that ? Can you please post an answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `api_key_from_network` is global for your class. so use `AsyncTask` to do Network Operation and get data and in `Post Execution` assign it to variable.

```
public class get_key extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute (){
    //Show Dialog Here
        super.onPreExecute ();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground (String... params){

    // Do Network Calling
    return string;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute (String result){

     if(dialog.isShowing()){
     dialog.dismiss();
     }
    // put condition to check data
    api_key_from_network=reuslt;
    }
 }
```

just run new `get_key().execute();` where you want to get key from network.

Comment: Okay now do I place `get_key().execute()` after the class or before the class. Because it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: if you want to get key in login button click execute this asynctask in login.onclick method.

Comment: I get this error `varible is accessed from inner class, needs to be declared final`. If i modify it to final, it says `cannot assign value to final variable`

Comment: `String api_key_from_network;` put this after `public class Login extends ActionBarActivity{` line make it global.

Comment: yeah when I did that it said, `Method does not override from superclass`

Comment: my `doInBackground()` method does not take any argument ?

Comment: you need some tutorial to know how to use AsynTask, check [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/os/asynctask/android-asynctask-example/) for general idea.

Comment: I cannot seem to call the execute function is what I meant

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80383/discussion-between-shvet-and-magesh-kumaar).

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it is using interfaces.   May you figure out some idea from this eample

```
public interface AsyncTaskListener<String> {
    public void onReceivingApiKey(String result);
}

public class AsyncTaskGetApiKey extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    ArrayList<AsyncTaskListener<String>> listeners;

    public AsyncTaskLoadingInSplash() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<AsyncTaskListener<String>>();
    }

    public void addListener(AsyncTaskListener<String> listener){
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(AsyncTaskListener<String> listener){
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return httpRequest.getHttpResponse(email,password);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        for (AsyncTaskListener<String> listener:listeners) {
            listener.onReceivingApiKey(result);
        }
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity
implements AsyncTaskListener<String>{

AsyncTaskGetApiKey task;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        task = new AsyncTaskGetApiKey();
        task.addListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceivingApiKey(String result) {
        //use the returned value
    }
}
```